# About using returned references

Tags: c++, reference

I'm having some trouble trying to understand proper usage of returned references in C++.
I have a class with a "big" object inside. I want to be able to use this object outside the class "read only" mode by returning a const reference to it.

The problem is I don't quite understand when objects get copied and when they don't.

Most of the questions about returning references where about returning objects allocating on the stack, which is not my particular problem, so I've prepared this little example:

```
class foo {
  int a;

public:
  foo() {
    a = 3;
  }

  int& getInt() {
    return a;
  }

  const int& useInt() {
    return a;
  }

  void print() {
    cout << "Inside class: a = " << a << endl;
  }
};

int main() {
  foo foo1;

  int& goodRef = foo1.getInt();
  int badRef = foo1.getInt();

  goodRef = 4;
  badRef = 5;

  foo1.print();

  foo1.getInt() = 6;
  foo1.print();

  int usingIt = 10*foo1.useInt();
}
```

What I understand is:

- In `int& goodRef = foo1.getInt();` nothing is copied, only the class owned *a* exists.
- In `int badRef = foo1.getInt();` badRef is a copy of a, so there are 2 separate objects, *a* and *badRef*.

So depending on what type of object catches the return value it is copied or it is not, so my question is:

When I use the reference like in `int usingIt = 10*foo1.useInt();` is it copied and then used to multiply or only the value inside the class is used?

In this example it doesn't matter since it is only an int, but if it was a big object it would be a big deal.

Thanks!

**Edit:** Thanks to all the answers, but I get that having such methods inside a class is bad, I only put them for the sake of the example.

My actual class has a bunch of objects inside and an interface and bla bla, but one particular object is a glm::mat4. What i want is to be able to write something like `glm::vec4 finalVec = foo1.getMatrix() * vec`. But I dont want the whole matrix to be copied and then multiplied, rather I want to use the matrix that is already inside my class to perform the multiplication and at the same time not let the user modify it. I supposed something similar to `useInt` but with the mat4 would work but I wasn't sure and that's why I asked the question.

The glm specificatioon is very confuse for me, but I think the operator * is described as:

`glm::mat4 operator* (glm::mat4 const & m, glm::vec4 const & v);`

Comment: What you are doing is very bad design! Information hiding is one of the OO principals. So you should not give a reference to anything which is "internal". Please provide methods to class which can be used to act with the internal data!

Comment: The question is, what does `operator *` return? A copy?

Comment: Yes, I think it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example `int usingIt = 10*foo1.useInt();`, the `operator*()`, depending on it's argument signature and internals, could cause a copy of your object to take place, at which point it would then be assigned (rather than copied again) into the value of `usingIt`.  If your object was an aggregate or class object type, the copy using the object type's assignment operator would typically be elided using a compiler optimization step.

In general, anytime you are copying a l-value reference type (i.e., `T&` or `const T&`) to an aggregate or class object to a non-reference type (i.e., type `T`), a copy constructor, constructor, assignment operator, or conversion operator is invoked on the returned reference to the object.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I edited my post, what I want is to access a matrix that is inside my class to perform a multiplication only, so I dont need the whole matrix to be copied, I just want to use it to multiply another vector, and at the same time I dont want the user to be able to modify such matrix outside the interface my class provides. What you are saying is that there is no way of doing `glm::vec4 finalVec = myClass1.getMatrix() * someVec` without the whole matrix being copied?

Comment: That will depend on how you want your `operator*()` to work ... if it accepts a `const T&` argument, then your matrix object won't be copied at all.  Generally an `operator*()` between two objects of type `T` will return a copied type `T` object though, and that is what I was alluding to in my answer (I've edited it to be a little more explanatory).

Answer (score 0):

When you use const reference you can only use const methods of this object. E.g. when you have STL vector you can get size, but you can't push_back elements to it.

```
vector<int> a;
vector<int> &c = a;
const vector<int> &b = a;
a.size();
b.size();
a.push_back(4);
c.push_back(4);
//our vector is now 4 4
//b.push_back(4); compilation error
```

In C++ you copy when you want to copy: for example
Function which copies:
`int x(vector<int> b)`

Function which doesn't copy:
`int x(vector<int> &b)`

[You can read more here](http://www.drbio.cornell.edu/pl47/programming/TICPP-2nd-ed-Vol-one-html/Chapter11.html)

Answer (score 0):

If `getInt` returns `int&` why are you catching the return value in an `int`? What do you expect, that the compiler changes your source code to use a reference to int? It can't do anything else than copying the value of the object pointed by the reference.

On the other hand I think you have a bad example. Either you define a single method that returns a const reference:

```
int const & getInt() { return a; }
```

Or you provide two methods, one const and one non const:

```
int& getInt() { return a; }

int const & getInt() const { return a; }
```

Having both `getInt` and `useInt` does not stop anyone from using `getInt` and actually changing the value of the object in an way that is not intended.

Comment: Thanks, the getInt method was only to clarify what references do and do not do, I would never implement such thing inside an actual class. My class is a proper class but the method I am interested in is something similar to useInt(), where the user can **use** the object but not **modify** it, without the object being copied in between (user accesses class member object). Thats why I thought about returning a const reference, but I dont know if the copy operation would be perforemed anyway or not. More deatails in the edited post. Thanks for your patience.